# How to change Storage Mode to Modem Mode

Tags: usb-modem

My modem isn't in the device list of `usb_modeswitch` so I cannot automatically use the modem in Ubuntu.

I found the way to change the modem from **USB Storage Mode** to **Modem Mode** and I can use my modem. But I forgot the instructions.

My modem information:

`vendor/product id: 05 Qualcomm, Inc. Mass Storage Device`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with those 3g modems, I've set mine up a while ago and forgot about it as well. I do remember however that in some cases all I needed was ejecting the virtual CD device provided by the dongle using the `eject -r /dev/<device>` command.

If you don't know your CDROM device's name you could try finding it by plugging in your modem and running:

```
dmesg | egrep -i 'dvd|cd'
```

Comment: how to know which device to eject....

Comment: I updated my answer.